# Align submenu to centre of parent

Tags: html, css

I've got a CSS Menu, When hovering over the List Item, It loads in the sub menu. All works fine, I've put an before & after class on the menu so that it creates an arrow at the top of it.

But I've got an issue in that the arrow, Just is not in the middle of the text that its' relative to.

My CSS is :

```
/* Nav
----------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
.navigation {
  background: #6aa7b9;
  border-top-right-radius: 150px;
  height: 52px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 999;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navigation {
    height: 0;
  }
}
.menu-main-menu-container {
  padding-top: 0.8em;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .menu-main-menu-container {
    padding-top: 0;
  }
}
.main-menu {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: right;
}
@media (max-width: 767px), (max-width: 991px), (max-width: 1199px) {
  .main-menu {
    text-align: left;
    display: none;
  }
}
@media (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : landscape) {
  .main-menu {
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: right;
    background: none;
  }
}
.menu-item {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 3em;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: .5em;
  padding-top: 0.5em;
}
.menu-item.current_page_item {
  border-bottom: 5px solid #561f38;
}
.menu-item.current_page_item a {
  color: #561f38;
}
.menu-item.current_page_item ul li a {
  color: #ffffff;
}
.menu-item:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
.menu-item a {
  font-family: freight-sans-pro, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-style: normal;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 15px;
}
.menu-item a:hover {
  color: #561f38;
}
.menu-item a span.hover-large {
  position: absolute;
  width: 70px;
  height: 80px;
  z-index: 999;
}
.menu-item ul {
  background: #561f38;
  position: absolute;
  left: -75px;
  top: 56px;
  padding: 0;
  z-index: 99999999;
  width: 215px;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  -webkit-transition: 500ms ease;
  -moz-transition: 500ms ease;
  -o-transition: 500ms ease;
  transition: 500ms ease;
}
.menu-item ul:after,
.menu-item ul:before {
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  border: solid transparent;
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.menu-item ul:after {
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border-width: 8px;
  margin-left: -8px;
}
.menu-item ul:before {
  border-color: rgba(232, 238, 234, 0);
  border-bottom-color: #561f38;
  border-width: 14px;
  margin-left: -14px;
}
.menu-item ul li {
  padding-left: 2em;
  padding-right: 2em;
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: 0;
  display: block;
  margin-right: 0;
}
.menu-item ul li.current_page_item {
  background: #fafafb;
  border-bottom: none;
}
.menu-item ul li.current_page_item a {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #561f38;
}
.menu-item ul li a {
  color: #ffffff;
}
.menu-item ul li:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}
.menu-item ul li:hover {
  background: #fafafb;
  border-bottom: none;
}
.menu-item ul li:hover a {
  color: #561f38;
}
.menu-item ul li:hover a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.menu-item ul li a {
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 0.5em;
  display: block;
}
.menu-item ul li:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}
.menu-item:hover {
  border-bottom: 5px solid #561f38;
}
.menu-item:hover > ul {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}
@media (max-width: 767px), (max-width: 991px) {
  .main-menu {
    background: #f2f5f6;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 0.5em;
    padding-bottom: 0.5em;
  }
  .main-menu:after,
  .main-menu:before {
    bottom: 100%;
    right: 15px;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
  }
  .main-menu:after {
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-bottom-color: #;
    border-width: 8px;
    margin-left: -8px;
  }
  .main-menu:before {
    border-color: rgba(232, 238, 234, 0);
    border-bottom-color: #e8eeea;
    border-width: 14px;
    margin-left: -14px;
  }
  .menu-item {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 1em;
  }
  .menu-item.current_page_item {
    border-bottom: none;
  }
  .menu-item.current_page_item a {
    color: #eb2328;
  }
  .menu-item.current_page_item ul li a {
    color: #561f38;
  }
  .menu-item a {
    display: block;
    color: #561f38;
  }
  .menu-item a span {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 37px;
    height: 20px;
    z-index: 999;
  }
  .menu-item a span.hover-large {
    display: none;
  }
  .menu-item a span.chevron-down {
    background: url(../img/icons/icon-arrow-down.png) no-repeat;
  }
  .menu-item a span.chevron-up {
    background: url(../img/icons/icon-arrow-up.png) no-repeat;
  }
  .menu-item ul.sub-menu {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative !important;
    display: none;
    top: 0 !important;
    opacity: 1;
    padding-top: 0.5em;
    padding-bottom: 0.5em;
    visibility: visible;
    left: 0;
    background: #f2f5f6;
  }
  .menu-item ul.sub-menu::before {
    display: none;
  }
  .menu-item ul.sub-menu li.current_page_item a {
    color: #561f38;
  }
  .menu-item ul.sub-menu li a {
    color: #561f38;
  }
  .menu-item a {
    color: #561f38;
  }
}
@media (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : landscape) {
  .main-menu {
    background: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: right;
  }
}
```

HTML Markup **Note:** I'm using Wordpress

```
<ul id="menu" class="main-menu"><li id="menu-item-24" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home menu-item-24"><a href="http://localhost/crofton-infants/"><span class="hover-large"></span>Home</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-25" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-10 current_page_item menu-item-has-children menu-item-25"><a href="http://localhost/crofton-infants/our-school/"><span class="hover-large"></span>Our School<span class="chevron-down"></span></a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-90" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-90"><a href="http://localhost/crofton-infants/our-school/staff/"><span class="hover-large"></span>Staff</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-86" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-86"><a href="http://localhost/crofton-infants/our-school/governors/"><span class="hover-large"></span>Governors</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-85" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-85"><a href="http://localhost/crofton-infants/our-school/classes/"><span class="hover-large"></span>Classes</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-87" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-87"><a href="http://localhost/crofton-infants/our-school/parents-friends-association/"><span class="hover-large"></span>Parents / Friends Association</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-89" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-89"><a href="http://localhost/crofton-infants/our-school/school-council/"><span class="hover-large"></span>School Council</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-88" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-88"><a href="http://localhost/crofton-infants/our-school/philosophy/"><span class="hover-large"></span>Philosophy</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-26" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-26"><a href="http://localhost/crofton-infants/parents/"><span class="hover-large"></span>Parents<span class="chevron-down"></span></a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-96" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-96"><a href="http://localhost/crofton-infants/parents/uniforms/"><span class="hover-large"></span>Uniforms</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-95" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-95"><a href="http://localhost/crofton-infants/parents/school-dinners/"><span class="hover-large"></span>School Dinners</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-93" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-93"><a href="http://localhost/crofton-infants/parents/calendar/"><span class="hover-large"></span>Calendar</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-91" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-91"><a href="http://localhost/crofton-infants/parents/absence-reporting/"><span class="hover-large"></span>Absence Reporting</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-92" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-92"><a href="http://localhost/crofton-infants/parents/admissions/"><span class="hover-large"></span>Admissions</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-94" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-94"><a href="http://localhost/crofton-infants/parents/letters-home/"><span class="hover-large"></span>Letters Home</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-22" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-22"><a href="http://localhost/crofton-infants/curriculum/"><span class="hover-large"></span>Curriculum<span class="chevron-down"></span></a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-75" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-75"><a href="http://localhost/crofton-infants/curriculum/maths/"><span class="hover-large"></span>Maths</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-76" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-76"><a href="http://localhost/crofton-infants/curriculum/phonics/"><span class="hover-large"></span>Phonics</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-23" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-23"><a href="http://localhost/crofton-infants/essential-information/"><span class="hover-large"></span>Essential Info<span class="chevron-down"></span></a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-82" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-82"><a href="http://localhost/crofton-infants/essential-information/safeguarding/"><span class="hover-large"></span>Safeguarding</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-79" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-79"><a href="http://localhost/crofton-infants/essential-information/ofsted/"><span class="hover-large"></span>Ofsted</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-78" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-78"><a href="http://localhost/crofton-infants/essential-information/data/"><span class="hover-large"></span>Data</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-77" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-77"><a href="http://localhost/crofton-infants/essential-information/attendance/"><span class="hover-large"></span>Attendance</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-81" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-81"><a href="http://localhost/crofton-infants/essential-information/pupil-premium/"><span class="hover-large"></span>Pupil Premium</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-84" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-84"><a href="http://localhost/crofton-infants/essential-information/sports-premium/"><span class="hover-large"></span>Sports Premium</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-83" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-83"><a href="http://localhost/crofton-infants/essential-information/send/"><span class="hover-large"></span>SEND</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-80" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-80"><a href="http://localhost/crofton-infants/essential-information/policies/"><span class="hover-large"></span>Policies</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-21" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-21"><a href="http://localhost/crofton-infants/contact/"><span class="hover-large"></span>Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

I've also made a [jSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1tuz7too/2/) of this

Is there a better / easier way to align the arrow / nav to it's parent and in the middle of it.

Thanks

Comment: Not a solution, but your JSFiddle has a typo in line 1: <div class+"navigation">

Comment: Should be fixed now, Will update URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
.menu-item ul {
  ...
  left: -75px;
  width: 215px;
  ...
}
```

use:

```
.menu-item ul {
  ...
  left: 50%;
  width: 216px;
  margin-left: -108px; /* half of width */
  ...
}
```

Your updated fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/1tuz7too/3/

Comment: That's great. Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

```
.menu-item ul {
  background: #561f38;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  top: 56px;
  padding: 0;
  z-index: 99999999;
  width: 215px;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  -webkit-transition: 500ms ease;
  -moz-transition: 500ms ease;
  -o-transition: 500ms ease;
  transition: 500ms ease;
}
```

instead of using

```
left: -75px;
```

use

```
left: 50%;
-webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
-moz-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
-ms-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
transform: translate(-50%, 0);
```